# IIS 8 https binding doesn't work without an http bind

Tags: asp.net, http, ssl, https, iis-8

In IIS 8 I have site bindings for both http and https (ports 80 and 443 respectively).  I can access both versions just fine at `http://www.hostname.com` and `https://www.hostname.com`, which is exactly what I would expect.

However, when I try to remove the standard http binding, both versions of the site time out (this timeout also happens when checking the "require SSL" checkbox in IIS).

How can I remove the http binding or otherwise force all traffic to the https version?

Comment: Please review your applicationHost.config file to see what bindings remain. A site can definitely live with only HTTPS bindings. Even if something bad happens on your machine and you have to keep an HTTP binding, you can use URL Rewrite to redirect all HTTP access to HTTPS.

Comment: When I remove the http binding, the applicationHost.config file has one binding entry for this particular site: `<binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:443:www.hostname.com" sslFlags="0" />` Unfortunately I'm not familiar enough with wildcards and such to know if this is correct.